# How many Automation will Create & Run In marketing cloud For standard success plan?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

How many automation run & create in a month?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the success plan (which is defining the level of support received by you from Salesforce). You should instead look at the edition. Here you can see how many automation runs are included in respective editions:

[image]

[Source](https://brandcdn.exacttarget.com/sites/exacttarget/files/editions_comparison_data_sheet_-_marketing_cloud_v2.pdf)